# Changing Service Account Causes Services to not Start

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, coldfusion

In testing rotating the password for the service account running Coldfusion 10 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 R2 in a POC environment, the Jetty service fails to start.  Initially, all Coldfusion related services are using the development account and I change it to the POC account.  The services are restarted, however, the ODBC Agent service, ODBC Server service, and Jetty service fail to start.  However, the ODBC related services are remedied by deleting the *.trc files in C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\db\slserver54\tracing.

Restarting the server has had no effect in getting the service started.  When using the services snap in, the service sometimes starts and immediately stops or displays "The ColdFusion 10 Jetty Service service on Local Computer started and then stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

During this condition, the Coldfusion Administrator console does not load and displays a 500 error with the Administrator styling.

Are there any thoughts as to how I may resolve this?

Comment: You need to/should be using Managed Service Accounts for this. This is the exact reason for Managed Service Accounts. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560633(v=ws.10).aspx